# Are Hamachi minecraft servers always running

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hamachi

So I made (am making, actually) a Minecraft server with Hamachi and I want to know if the server, once made, is always running or not. This "always running" problem is why I am making a Hamachi server instead of a port forwarding one. However, if Hamachi is similar to port forwarding in that you must click a `start.command` file and you need the `start.command` file to be on for the server to be running I will abandon it and probably start crying unless I can run it 24/7 on my computer, which if I can I would like to know how as well. Thanks!

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting?

Comment: I think the downvotes are probably due to the fact that it's unclear what you're asking. No part of what you describe (using Hamachi server, `start.command` file) influences server uptime.

Comment: @Hazard - Possibly because Hamachi isn't considered a good solution. It's buggy, and can be difficult to set up in its own right. It's also known to use publiccally allocated IP addresses illegally. (https://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/Hamachi-is-using-ILLEGAL-IP-ranges/td-p/83746).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got your wires a little crossed for this one.

The always-on nature of a server doesn't really have anything to do with the networking side. As long as hamachi is running, and logged in, and the server program is running, people will be able to connect to your server.

if you shutdown the machine, you will need to start hamachi and the server program again when you start the machine up again.

As said in my comment above, Hamachi is bad. Please don't use it. Get  a dedicated machine, and use port forwarding to allow access.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I use port forwarding :). Gonna run my minecraft server on my old never-used computer

Comment: Please consider up-voting and 'accept' ing this answer if you feel it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, you need to have both Hamachi turned on and the server console file turned on for the server to be running.

Everyone who wants to connect to your server has to be connected to the Hamachi server first (naturally).

Comment: Ok, so basically you're saying that unless the `start.command` file is clicked the server isn't running?

Comment: Essentially yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm gonna find out how to run my server 24/7 automated.